# c++ efficiently draw line over background image

Tags: c++, canvas, vcl

A `TBitmap* prevImg` object takes some time to be generated, so I generate it once and want to set it as a *background*:

```
Image1->Picture->Assign(prevImg); //TImage* Image1
```

Now I want to paint some lines and numbers on mousemove on top of this:

```
void __fastcall TTriggerSystemForm::Image1MouseMove(TObject *Sender, TShiftState Shift, int X, int Y){
  if(!prevImg)return;
  Image1->Picture->Assign(prevImg); //reset image

  Image1->Canvas->Pen->Color=clRed; //draw a vertical dotted red line
  Image1->Canvas->Pen->Style=psDot;
  Image1->Canvas->MoveTo(X,0);
  Image1->Canvas->LineTo(X,Image1->Picture->Height);
}
```

Now this is working already fine. However, since the image is sometimes blinking and the task's CPU goes up to 8% just because of this mousemove-Event, this is probably not very effective.

I'm using C++ Builder XE2 with VCL.

**Is there a better way to draw something dynamically on a given TImage object without changing the original image source?**

Comment: It will be more efficient by using `MouseDown` event instead of `MouseMove`. Why you need to use the `MouseMove` event to draw a line over your `TImage` ?

Comment: Draw the background once, then keep a copy. When you need to update the screen, make another copy of this background, draw your lines onto this offscreen copy, then blast it onto the screen and throw it away. Flicker is all but gone and your expensive to create background is copied inexpensively.

Answer (score 0):

Read about double buffering, the trick is that you are drawing on a different buffer and once your job is complete you switch the buffers. This will prevent 'blinking'.

To lower the CPU usage you could minimize the number of processed mouse events, for instance by skipping processing of the event if the time from the last processed one is lower than 100-200ms

Comment: when I use an additional `TBitmap *prevImgOut` object, which I draw everything on and in the end, call `Image1->Draw(0,0,prevImgOut)`, the CPU usage will increase. Is there a better way to "switch buffers" ? `Image1->Picture->Assign(prevImgOut)` is even worse...

Comment: I suppose that you are just drawing it too often.
Try with some 'ignore time' as I have mentioned in the answer.

You can also optimize your algorithm by redrawing only the part of the rect that changed since last time instead of whole bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply draw the portions of the image that are actually changing, instead of drawing the entire image, eg:

```
int oldX = -1;

void __fastcall TTriggerSystemForm::Image1MouseMove(TObject *Sender, TShiftState Shift, int X, int Y)
{
    if (!prevImg) return;

    if (!Image1->Picture->Graphic)
        Image1->Picture->Assign(prevImg); //reset image

    if (oldX == X) return;

    if (oldX != -1)
    {
        TRect r = Rect(oldX, 0, oldX + Image1->Canvas->Pen->Width, Image1->Height);
        Image1->Canvas->CopyRect(r, prevImg->Canvas, r);
    }

    Image1->Canvas->Pen->Color = clRed; //draw a vertical dotted red line
    Image1->Canvas->Pen->Style = psDot;
    Image1->Canvas->MoveTo(X, 0);
    Image1->Canvas->LineTo(X, Image1->Height);

    oldX = X;
}
```

That being said, I would suggest using a `TPaintBox` instead of a `TImage`, eg:

```
int MouseX = -1;

void __fastcall TTriggerSystemForm::PaintBox1MouseMove(TObject *Sender, TShiftState Shift, int X, int Y)
{
    MouseX = X;
    PaintBox1->Invalidate();
}

void __fastcall TTriggerSystemForm::PaintBox1MouseMove(TObject *Sender)
{
    if (!prevImg) return;
    PaintBox1->Canvas->Draw(0, 0, prevImg); //reset image

    if (MouseX != -1)
    {
        PaintBox1->Canvas->Pen->Color = clRed; //draw a vertical dotted red line
        PaintBox1->Canvas->Pen->Style = psDot;
        PaintBox1->Canvas->MoveTo(MouseX, 0);
        PaintBox1->Canvas->LineTo(MouseX, PaintBox1->Height);
    }
}
```